# Android: Want to select only one imageview at a time using Fragment

Tags: android, fragment

I set the 4 `ImageView` as a bottom menu.
I want to select one image at that time other three were deselected.

When i move to the next screen i want particular image selected which i set.
I used 2 images for each `ImageView` 1 for Deselect(gray) and another for Selected(Blue).

here i am posting my complete code:-

**HomePage.Java**

```
public class HomePage extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    ImageView mHomeButton,mattendence,mTarget,mReport;
    public HomePage() {};
    Activity activity;
    View view;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        // don't look at this layout it's just a listView to show how to handle the keyboard
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_home_page, container, false);
        getActivity().setTitle("HomePage");
        mHomeButton = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.fHome);
        mattendence = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.fAttendence);
        mTarget = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.fTarget);
        mReport = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.fReport);

        mHomeButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        mattendence.setOnClickListener(this);
        mTarget.setOnClickListener(this);
        mReport.setOnClickListener(this);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mHomeButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.home);
        mattendence.setImageResource(R.drawable.att);
        mTarget.setImageResource(R.drawable.target);
        mReport.setImageResource(R.drawable.report);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this.getActivity(), HomePage.class);
        int selected = 0;


        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.fHome:
                mHomeButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.blue);

                selected =1;
                Fragment con = new HomePage();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.framelayout, con).commit();
                break;
            // define same as all other views
            case R.id.fAttendence:
                mattendence.setImageResource(R.drawable.blue);
                selected = 2;
                con = new Attendence();
                fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.framelayout, con).commit();

                break;
            case R.id.fTarget:
                mTarget.setImageResource(R.drawable.blue);
                selected =3;
                con = new Payment();
                fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.framelayout, con).commit();

                break;
            case R.id.fReport:
                mReport.setImageResource(R.drawable.blue);
                selected =4;
                con = new Delivery();
                fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.framelayout, con).commit();

                break;
        }
        intent.putExtra("selected",selected);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

in another activity

**Attendence.Java**

```
public class Attendence extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{
    ImageView mHomeButton,mattendence,mTarget,mReport;
    public Attendence(){};
    Activity activity;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        // don't look at this layout it's just a listView to show how to handle the keyboard
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_attendence, container, false);
        getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        getActivity().setTitle("My Attendence");
        activity = getActivity();
        mHomeButton = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.fHome);
        mattendence = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.fAttendence);
        mTarget = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.fTarget);
        mReport = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.fReport);

        mHomeButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        mattendence.setOnClickListener(this);
        mTarget.setOnClickListener(this);
        mReport.setOnClickListener(this);


        return  view;

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mHomeButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.home);
        mattendence.setImageResource(R.drawable.att);
        mTarget.setImageResource(R.drawable.target);
        mReport.setImageResource(R.drawable.report);
        int selected = getActivity().getIntent().getIntExtra("selected",2);
            switch(selected){

                case 1:
                    mHomeButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.blue);
                    Fragment con1 = new HomePage();
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager1 = getFragmentManager();
                    fragmentManager1.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.framelayout, con1).commit();

                    break;
                // define same as all other views
                case 2:
                    mattendence.setImageResource(R.drawable.blue);
                    Fragment con2 = new Attendence();
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager2 = getFragmentManager();
                    fragmentManager2.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.framelayout, con2).commit();

                    break;
                case 3:
                    mTarget.setImageResource(R.drawable.blue);
                    Fragment con3 = new Payment();
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager3 = getFragmentManager();
                    fragmentManager3.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.framelayout, con3).commit();


                    break;
                case 4:
                    mReport.setImageResource(R.drawable.blue);
                    Fragment con4 = new Delivery();
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager4 = getFragmentManager();
                    fragmentManager4.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.framelayout, con4).commit();
                    break; }

        }

    }
```

**Delivery.Java**

```
public class Delivery extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

    ImageView mHomeButton,mattendence,mTarget,mReport;
    Activity activity;

    public Delivery(){};

    View view;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        // don't look at this layout it's just a listView to show how to handle the keyboard
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_delivery, container, false);
        getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        getActivity().setTitle("Delivery");
        activity = getActivity();
        mHomeButton = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.fHome);
        mattendence = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.fAttendence);
        mTarget = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.fTarget);
        mReport = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.fReport);

        mHomeButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        mattendence.setOnClickListener(this);
        mTarget.setOnClickListener(this);
        mReport.setOnClickListener(this);

        return  view;

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mHomeButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.home);
        mattendence.setImageResource(R.drawable.att);
        mTarget.setImageResource(R.drawable.target);
        mReport.setImageResource(R.drawable.report);
        int selected = getActivity().getIntent().getIntExtra("selected",4);

        switch(selected){
            case 1:
                mHomeButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.blue);
                Fragment con1 = new HomePage();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager1 = getFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager1.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.framelayout, con1).commit();

                break;
            // define same as all other views
            case 2:
                mattendence.setImageResource(R.drawable.blue);
                Fragment con2 = new Attendence();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager2 = getFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager2.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.framelayout, con2).commit();

                break;
            case 3:
                mTarget.setImageResource(R.drawable.blue);
                Fragment con3 = new Payment();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager3 = getFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager3.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.framelayout, con3).commit();


                break;
            case 4:
                mReport.setImageResource(R.drawable.blue);
                Fragment con4 = new Delivery();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager4 = getFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager4.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.framelayout, con4).commit();
                break;

        }


    }

    }
```

**Payment.Java**

```
public class Payment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    ImageView mHomeButton, mattendence, mTarget, mReport;
    public Payment() {};
    View view;
    Activity activity;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        // don't look at this layout it's just a listView to show how to handle the keyboard
        activity = getActivity();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_payment, container, false);
        getActivity().setTitle("Payment");
        mHomeButton = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.fHome);
        mattendence = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.fAttendence);
        mTarget = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.fTarget);
        mReport = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.fReport);

        mHomeButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        mattendence.setOnClickListener(this);
        mTarget.setOnClickListener(this);
        mReport.setOnClickListener(this);

        return view;
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mHomeButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.home);
        mattendence.setImageResource(R.drawable.att);
        mTarget.setImageResource(R.drawable.target);
        mReport.setImageResource(R.drawable.report);
        int selected = getActivity().getIntent().getIntExtra("selected",3);
        switch(selected){

            case 1:
                mHomeButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.blue);
                Fragment con1 = new HomePage();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager1 = getFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager1.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.framelayout, con1).commit();

                break;
            // define same as all other views
            case 2:
                mattendence.setImageResource(R.drawable.blue);
                Fragment con2 = new Attendence();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager2 = getFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager2.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.framelayout, con2).commit();

                break;
            case 3:
                mTarget.setImageResource(R.drawable.blue);
                Fragment con3 = new Payment();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager3 = getFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager3.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.framelayout, con3).commit();


                break;
            case 4:
                mReport.setImageResource(R.drawable.blue);
                Fragment con4 = new Delivery();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager4 = getFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager4.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.framelayout, con4).commit();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

as like **Payment.Java** I created 2 more class name as **Delivery.Java** & **Attendence.Java**.

I am getting an Error like :-

```
Process: com.example.sachin.omcommunication, PID: 23488
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.sachin.omcommunication/com.example.sachin.omcommunication.HomePage}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1794)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1630)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4549)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityFromFragment(Activity.java:4535)
        at android.app.Activity$HostCallbacks.onStartActivityFromFragment(Activity.java:6609)
        at android.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:1092)
        at android.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:1071)
        at com.example.sachin.omcommunication.HomePage.onClick(HomePage.java:85)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

**manifest file**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.sachin.omcommunication">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".Splash" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Login" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Home"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_home"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>

        <HostActivity android:name=".HomePage"/>
        <HostActivity android:name=".Visit" />
        <HostActivity  android:name=".Order" />
        <HostActivity  android:name=".Payment" />
        <HostActivity  android:name=".Delivery"/>
        <HostActivity  android:name=".AddTask" />
        <HostActivity  android:name=".ScheduleTask" />
        <HostActivity  android:name=".OneTimeTask" />
        <HostActivity  android:name=".Attendence" />
        <HostActivity  android:name=".LeaveApplication" />
        <HostActivity  android:name=".Profile"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Please help me out of this..

Comment: _android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class com.example.sachin.omcommunication.HomePage have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?_

Comment: @KNeerajLal yes i declare should i paste my maifest here for better understanding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are tying to load a `Fragment` using an `Intent`,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this.getActivity(), HomePage.class);
intent.putExtra("selected",selected);
startActivity(intent);
```

`HomePage` is a `Fragment`. You cannot load it using `Intent`. Remove these lines from the code. This will solve your error.

Now to your image selection issue.

You are selecting an image and trying to pass the selected image index to each of your fragments.

```
int selected = getActivity().getIntent().getIntExtra("selected", index); // This is wrong
```

You need to change your approach at this problem. With your current approach you need to keep passing values from one fragment to another. Which is messy (IMHO).

A better way is to put the footer only in your Activity (Home.java). So that you don't have to bother about passing the values at all. Your Activity's xml you need the following layout.

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout android:id= "@+id/R.id.framelayout" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        layout="@layout/footer"/>

<LinearLayout>
```

Manage the clicks only in this `Activity`. So you don't have to manage the clicks in the `Fragment`.

**EDIT**

You can also use [FragmentTabHost](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v13/app/FragmentTabHost.html). By default the tabs are shown above the screen, which is recommended by android. You can bring it down. [Here](https://github.com/rameshkec85/BottomTabsFragmentTabHost) and [here](https://maxalley.wordpress.com/2013/05/18/android-creating-a-tab-layout-with-fragmenttabhost-and-fragments/) are some examples.

You need to call the `setup()` method of the `FragmentTabHost` to initialize it. The content are is loaded as `Fragments`. Use `newTabSpec()` method to add tabs to it.

[Tabhost tutorial](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/creating-navigation-tabs-using-tabhost-and-fragments-in-android/)

Good luck :)

Comment: i tried it too but the problem is while i moved to the next screen the imageview is deselected bt i want it as a selected.

Comment: @SachinSolanki Which is the "next screen"? Where are you trying to show the images?

Comment: the next screen will be Attendence.xml . but it will depends on a user i set the 4 imageview as an menu whichever user select at that time it will move to that screen

Comment: The `footer.xml` is incuded in all layouts?

Comment: only in Home.xml should i include the footer??

Comment: can i get the sample code for this?  just a little more explaination needed with example...

Comment: the previous method is good for me because i want to add popup on last imageview.. and rytnow m wrking as u suggested before.. :)

Comment: And can we add popup on TabHost?

Comment: Yes you can add a popup.

Comment: @K Neeraj  can you please suggest me the Java code for the previous method? 
and here i have problem i implement the NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener  in Home.Java so how can i implement View.OnClickListener??

Comment: Please post it as a new question.

Comment: okey ill and can u please suggest me a code for Select an ImageView ??

Comment: I gave you one in my answer.

Comment: @K Neeraj Lal please go to this link and suggest me the answer 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39426191/how-can-i-implement-view-onclicklistener-while-i-already-implements-navigationvi

Comment: @k Neeraj Lal i tried to use Tabs instead of images.. as a bottom menu and in my application i am using navigation drawer, so the problem is when i select any item from drawer then it is displaying down to the `Tabs`. how can i solve this?

Comment: Please post it as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

It clearly says you did not declared the class in `Manifest.xml`

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.sachin.omcommunication/com.example.sachin.omcommunication.HomePage}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

Try adding and update if any error.

Comment: @SachinSolanki The program is pure, try changing `HostActivity` to `Activity`.